# C++ std::map. Crash

Tags: c++, clang

При каких условия может произойти Segmentation fault при проверки контейнера на пустоту(empty)? Или поиск по койнтейнеру? Если учесть что в этот контейнер никто не пишет из другого потока...

Clang 4.0

Лог 1

```
#0  0x0000555558582d12 in std::less<unsigned int>::operator() (this=0x7fff7ec34868, __x=@0x656f5f6515a0: <error reading variable>, __y=@0x7fffffffd494: 38) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386
#1  0x00005555595784e1 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> > >::_M_lower_bound (this=0x7fff7ec34868, __x=0x656f5f651580, __y=0x7fff7ec34870, __k=@0x7fffffffd494: 38) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1670
#2  0x00005555595777c7 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> > >::find (this=0x7fff7ec34868, __k=@0x7fffffffd494: 38) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:2334
#3  0x0000555559576cf5 in std::map<unsigned int, FactionState, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> > >::find (this=0x7fff7ec34868, __x=@0x7fffffffd494: 38) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:1105
```

Лог 2

```
#0  0x0000555559cf87c5 in std::_Deque_iterator<unsigned char, unsigned char&, unsigned char*>::_M_set_node (this=0x7fff8b7fd220, __new_node=0x81ff0efa3dd8) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_deque.h:255
#1  0x0000555559d03500 in std::_Deque_iterator<unsigned char, unsigned char&, unsigned char*>::operator+= (this=0x7fff8b7fd220, __n=0) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_deque.h:217
#2  0x0000555559cf86b3 in std::_Deque_iterator<unsigned char, unsigned char&, unsigned char*>::operator+ (this=0x7fff8b7fd3f0, __n=0) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_deque.h:228
#3  0x0000555559ce7ebe in std::deque<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_erase (this=0x7fff8f0417b0, __position=0 '\000') at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/deque.tcc:235
#4  0x0000555559cd60e0 in std::deque<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::erase (this=0x7fff8f0417b0, __position=0 '\000') at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_deque.h:1748
```

Лог 3

```
#0  0x00005555595783d4 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> > >::_S_right (__x=0xc650bdc0ba50ba0) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:701
#1  0x0000555559577698 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> > >::_M_erase (this=0x7fff8f45fdd8, __x=0xc650bdc0ba50ba0) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1638
#2  0x00005555595776ab in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> > >::_M_erase (this=0x7fff8f45fdd8, __x=0x7fff1d9c056a) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1638
#3  0x0000555559cc5d19 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> > >::~_Rb_tree (this=0x7fff8f45fdd8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:873
#4  0x0000555559cc06ca in std::map<unsigned int, FactionState, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, FactionState> > >::~map (this=0x7fff8f45fdd8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:96
#5  0x0000555559cc0785 in ReputationMgr::~ReputationMgr (this=0x7fff8f45fdd0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at
```

Лог 4 (не мап, но всё же)

```
#0  0x000055555a2c55f8 in std::vector<VMAP::MeshTriangle, std::allocator<VMAP::MeshTriangle> >::end (this=0x59fc0f98) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:576
#1  0x000055555a2c2afc in std::vector<VMAP::MeshTriangle, std::allocator<VMAP::MeshTriangle> >::empty (this=0x59fc0f98) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:745
#2  0x000055555a2c0cd0 in VMAP::GroupModel::IntersectRay (this=0x59fc0f60, ray=..., distance=@0x7fff8a7fa6cc: 50, stopAtFirstHit=false) at Models/WorldModel.cpp:393
#3  0x000055555a2c2183 in VMAP::WModelRayCallBack::operator() (this=0x7fff8a7fa680, ray=..., entry=0, distance=@0x7fff8a7fa6cc: 50, pStopAtFirstHit=false) at WorldModel.cpp:449
```

Comment: Например? Что за "UB"?

Comment: UB это акроним от Undefined Behavior. То есть "Неопределенное поведение"

Comment: По разнообразию контейнеров и вызывающих падение методов можно сделать предварительный вывод, что методы вызываются для уже уничтоженных объектов. Падение происходит при первом обращении к памяти через `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть очень много самых разных.

Из своего опыта сходу могу назвать такие:

1. К моменту обращения к функции empty уже выполнен деструктор (или что примерно то же самое - освобождение/выделение памяти).
2. Раз уж речь идет о thread'ах, то испортить map можно не только обращением к этому map'у, но и другими обращениями.

Очень рекомендую утилиту valgrind для отладки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да валгринд ничего в нужном месте не показывает если использовать в локальных условиях, а на продакшене его использовать нереально...

   насчёт пункта первого,имеете ввиду деструктор контейнера?

Comment: Да, деструктор контейнера. У меня нормальная практика - в ключевых деструкторах добавлять сообщение в журнал.

Comment: Ясно, добавил некоторые логи, что вы можете сказать по ним?

Comment: Смотреть логи без исходника не вижу смысла. А исходники у Вас я сильно подозреваю не маленькие. Так что навряд ли Вам можно вот так помочь. Тут главное успокоиться, отдохнуть, и на свежую голову еще раз внимательно проанализировать работу тредов и логику выделения/освобождения памяти.

Answer (score 0):

> Если учесть что в этот контейнер никто не пишет из другого потока...

Чтение по несуществующему ключу создаёт этот ключ и добавляет дефаултное значение для него. Так что не факт, что никто не пишет.

Comment: Такое ведь если обращаться к ключу контейнера через [ ]?

Comment: @user_21, да, через `[]`.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/178557)

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov, почему не является? Многопоточное добавление элементов в map разве не является UB?

Comment: @Qwertiy при всем уважении к вашему ответу, он все же больше напоминает комментарий, нежели полноценный ответ на вопрос (иначе вряд ли бы его добавили в "очередь проверок"). напишите более развернутый ответ на вопрос автора, чтобы не было разночтений.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov, вероятно, в очередь он попал автоматически за то, что короткий.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, скорее всего из-за этого.